# How to round figure if it is less then point 5 only in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to round my figure in JavaScript if it is less then any 0.5 figure. For Instance if I have value 3.4 then it should be 3 but if 3.5 then there is no need to round figure. I only want to round figure if it is less than 0.5. Here is the code I am using to round figure. But it rounded the figure in both cases

This code gives me result 3.5

```
function rounded(){
               var val = 3.5; 
                var rounded = Math.round(val);
                console.log("rounded",rounded);
}
```

and this code gives me result 4 but I want 3.5..

```
function rounded(){
                   var val = 3.6; 
                    var rounded = Math.round(val);
                    console.log("rounded",rounded);
    }
```

Any body can help me with this?

Comment: Use `(val%1)<.5 ? round(val) : val`

Comment: for 3.3 it  gives me 3.5 but I want 3.0 for less then 3.5 I want 3.0 and for greater then 3.6 I want 3.5

Comment: btw, the 1st code example you posted gives you 3 as a result. Math.round will round to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) to round down.

```
var round = function (num) {
   return Math.floor(num * 2) / 2;
};

console.log(round(3));  // 3
console.log(round(3.4));  // 3
console.log(round(3.5));  // 3.5
console.log(round(3.6));  // 3.5
console.log(round(4));  // 4
```

Comment: thank you so much its solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This should truncate to the nearest .5:

```
parseInt(x * 2) / 2;
```